# Data encryption with Core Data in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, encryption

I just need a confirmation on this.

Is it correct to say that, with the iPhone 3GS and above, any data written to the filesystem is encrypted using hardware encryption? By simply creating the XXX.sqlite file on the file system, the data stored in it is already encrypted.

Also for further security `NSFileProtectionComplete` is provided?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK that is the case only if the phone has a passcode and is in a locked state.

Comment: Also have a look at this WWDC session https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4088379409.04088379411.4092394151?i=1595505280

Answer (score 8):

```
[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{ NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete } error:&error]
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me- out of curiosity, does anyone think the Apple documentation for this is incorrect? The only mention I see of this option value is at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Spotlight_External_Record_Elements which does not seem correct.

Answer (score 7):

No, that is not correct. You will need to enable encryption on the sqlite file. Add the following after you create your `persistentStoreCoordinator`:

```
// Make sure the database is encrypted when the device is locked
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:[storeURL path] error:&error]) {
    // Deal with the error
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail to encrypt the Write-Ahead Log (WAL) file, which contains application data. This has to do with the journal mode used for sqlite, but be default it is now on. See the Comment below by Mike Rose and this blog post for more information: http://www.hopelessgeek.com/2014/10/10/core-data-and-data-protection/

Comment: @edsko Is it mandatory to turn on Data Protection in capabilities as well in order to complete the core data file encryption ?

Answer (score 3):

No, your assumption is not correct.

From the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator class documentation:

> The default value is NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication for all applications built on or after iOS v5.0. The default value for all older applications is NSFileProtectionNone.

To enable NSFileProtectionComplete, one would need to add the NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey with NSFileProtectionComplete to the options NSDictionary when calling the addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: method.

Keep in mind that this file encryption is only enabled when the user has set a passcode.