# Encryption with Core Data in background

Tags: ios, core-data, encryption

This question is different from questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690833/data-encryption-with-core-data-in-ios), because of the app being mostly in the background.

It is a requirement for our application that we keep the data store encrypted.

Our current implementation is using SQLite using SQLCipher. The plan is to move to Core Data.

I'm looking for a solution to keep the data encrypted, while still accessible in the background and is not restricting in terms of queries-NSPredicates and migration (schema change).

Below are all the options I've been looking into:

- NSFileProtectionComplete - will not allow file access in the background
- [encrypted-core-data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/) - This library does appear to be kept up-to-date. However, I've had second thoughts about using it in production after seeing the list of [known issues](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/issues?q=is%3Aopen). Has anyone used this recently?
- NSIncrementalStore - This was the way that Apple engineers recommended that we follow. encrypted-core-data is using this method.
- [Transformable Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html) in core data - is this solution scalable for larger data sets?

Does anyone have a recommendation that meets all of the criteria and can be used in production apps?

Answer (score 0):

I ran some proof-of-concept apps using each of the above options. I ran numbers and bench-maked it against our existing solution (SQLCipher).
Looks like using core data with incremental store (`encrypted-core-data`) came out to be the best.

After analyzing runtime performance times for read, write and search on DB with small and large sizes, `encrypted-core-data` turned out to be the most efficient and simpler to implement.